# InfoPath 2010 webservice connection error - 401 unauthorized - user profile service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, web-services, user-profile-service

The form works sometimes and doesn't other times, or it throws an error and still pulls the appropriate data.

All loopbacks have been disabled for all wfe and app servers.

I saw that some are adding host files to bypass the load balancer to prevent a double-hop but our admins say that we are not allowed to do that.

I also found out that the call is pulling back so much that it is taxing our servers. It's a complex form but the calls to the user profile service shouldn't be that big should it?

Comment: 401 Unauthorized could mean a couple things. Most likely the credentials you are using are incorrect or you don't have permission to call it. Test calls to the service outside of the InfoPath form to validate both of those scenarios.

Comment: Did that and everything is fine. It also works fine in Dev and QA, it's just prod causing the issues. I think it is probably something with the security and load balancing that's happening on prod. Still looking into it as time allows.

Comment: Any news on this?
I have the same issue on Prod but not in Dev/QA

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Claims Based Authentication?

My guess is that you are and you need to have that web service converted into a UDCX, edit the UDCX and add the authentication to point to a Secure Store Service Target Application ID. First create a SSS Target Application, that has access to the web service (generic account), then add the group of users to the members of the SSS. Name the Target Application ID: 'InfoPathWebService'

in the UDCX edit

```
<!–udc:Authentication><udc:SSO AppId=”CredentialType=” /></udc:Authentication–>
```

to

```
<udc:Authentication><udc:SSO AppId=’InfoPathWebService’ CredentialType=’NTLM’ /></udc:Authentication>
```

Save it and replace it in the same location you grabbed it from. Republish and try your forms again.

Detailed instructions are here: http://spvee.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/auto-populate-user-information-in-infopath-with-claims-based-authentication-part-3-of-3/

Comment: No, we use Kerberos. I got it working for PC with IE, chrome, and Firefox, but it's still throwing errors for Mac users on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Can't add comment, need 50 rep for that.

Do you have code behind in your Form?
Are you using default network credentials, or supplying user name, password?

Comment: No to the code behind. Yes for the network creds.